# Saving a query result into a temp table with unknown number of columns

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create the following function in plpgsql:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.select_all(query text)
RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    schemasT RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR schemasT IN (
        SELECT schema_name
        FROM information_schema.schemata
        WHERE schema_name IN (
            SELECT login 
            FROM cdu.nc_tenant
        )
    ) LOOP
        SET SEARCH PATH TO schemasT;
    
        EXECUTE query INTO something;
    END LOOP;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So that any query passed in to the function is ran into all schemas available and to return the results of a query. Using the function would be something like this:

```sql
pg_temp.select_all('SELECT count(1) FROM sku')
```

Would return:

| Schema | count |
| --- | --- |
| Schema1 | 58 |
| Schema2 | 42 |

And another example would be:

```sql
pg_temp.select_all('SELECT * FROM cdu.nc_tenant_variables where variable = ''theme''')
```

Would return:

| Schema | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Schema1 | theme | dark |
| Schema2 | theme | light |

**Why?**

Sometimes I need to query things across schemas and I am searching for a better way to do this instead of doing:

```
SELECT 'schema1' AS schema, count(1) FROM schema1.sku
UNION ALL
SELECT 'schema2' AS schema, count(1) FROM schema2.sku
UNION ALL
SELECT 'schema3' AS schema, count(1) FROM schema3.sku;
```

Comment: You can create an report schema model, and nigths you can fill this model from existing schemas. Then you can select in that reporting schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have somehow made it work, but it returns a JSON object rather than a normal table:

```
DROP FUNCTION pg_temp.select_all;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.select_all(query TEXT, whole int DEFAULT 0)
RETURNS table (j json) AS $$
DECLARE
    schemasT RECORD;
    counter int := 1;
    test RECORD;
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS resultquery;

    FOR schemasT IN (
        SELECT schema_name
        FROM information_schema.schemata
        WHERE schema_name IN (
            SELECT login 
            FROM cdu.nc_tenant
        )
    ) LOOP
        EXECUTE format('SET SEARCH_PATH TO %I', schemasT.schema_name);
        
        IF counter = 1 THEN
            EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE resultquery AS '|| query;
            ALTER TABLE pg_temp.resultquery ADD COLUMN tenant varchar;
            TRUNCATE TABLE resultquery;
        END IF;
    
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temptemp;
        EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE temptemp AS '|| query;
        ALTER TABLE pg_temp.temptemp ADD COLUMN tenant varchar;
        
        UPDATE pg_temp.temptemp SET tenant = schemasT.schema_name;
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO pg_temp.resultquery SELECT * FROM pg_temp.temptemp';
    
        counter := counter + 1;
    END LOOP;
    
    IF whole = 0 THEN
        RETURN QUERY  SELECT to_json(a) FROM (SELECT * FROM pg_temp.resultquery) a;
    ELSE 
        RETURN QUERY  SELECT json_agg(a) FROM (SELECT * FROM pg_temp.resultquery) a;
    END IF;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Using the function:

```
SELECT pg_temp.select_all('select count(1) from sku', 1);
```

Returns a one line JSON object